# Paypal IPN is not working in paypal account but its working correctly in sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Paypal IPN is not working in paypal account but its working correctly in sandbox. Please help us to solve the issue.How can we test these kind of situations if it occurs

Thanks

Comment: "not working" means? you do not receive an IPN? the parameters sent are "wrong"?

Comment: yes I am not getting IPN notification?

Comment: I am using paypal subscriptions

Comment: Are you using the sandobx & live paypals on the same machine? (or do you have a staging & live machines) did you make sure you pass the correct url in `notify_url`? are you using standard or pro?

Comment: I am using paypal standard. I am using same machines for it. Is It something related with text encoding ?

Comment: `    $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";`
`    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-   urlencoded\r\n";`
`    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";`
    `if($paypal_environment == "sandbox"){`
        `$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);`
    `}elseif ($paypal_environment == "paypal"){`
        `$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);`
   ` }`

Comment: Did you enable IPN on the live account?

Comment: I did set the url for the IPN

Comment: I also tested it by removing it from the page!

Comment: Did you make sure there is no error in your code? it's hard to debug those kinds of errors in an IPN handler.   At first just try to access your IPN handler directly from the browser and then use the IPN test tool at https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: In that way Its all working well ! not showing any error and working all the functionality after the IPN verification, the issue is when we go to live !

Comment: if (strcmp (strtoupper($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) this condition is  failing all the time. but the incoming value is "VERIFIED".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do notify_url setting in bussiness a/c of paypal

In addition to email notification, PayPal can send you the transaction data (also called Instant Payment Notification) to a specific url. With Instant Payment Notification, PayPal sends payment notification messages with encrypted code to the specified URL for each payment you receive. Follow the instructions below to setup Instant Payment Notification.

1. Go to the PayPal website and log in to your account.
2. Click "Profile" at the top of the page.
3. Click "Instant Payment Notification Preferences" in the Selling Preferences column.
4. Click "Edit IPN Settings."
5. Enter the notification URL and select "Receive IPN messages."

   example: http://yoursiteurl.com
6. Click "Save."